# Excel- I want to use conditional formatting to turn names yellow if they have dates that are past do in their row

Tags: excel

I have a spredsheet with employee names listed down column B,  in column E-EE  I have classes listed in the top row and  dates the class expire throughout the table,  I used conditional formatting to  color dates that will expire within 6 months  Yellow,  dates that are expired Red.  IF a person has any yellow or Red dates in their row, I want the name to turn Yellow.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0-TURIN7pKBQVV1cThnUnpIQjA

The Link is to a file with the conditional formatting for the part i can do   done,  I need to make the names turn Yellow if they have yellow or red in their row.

Comment: use a countif() to count if the dates in that row are less than 6 months.  IF it is greater than 0 return true for conditional Formatting.

Comment: like `=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(($E2:$EE2<=(NOW()+180))*($E2:$EE2>0)))`?

Comment: You are being downvoted because your link is broken. Fix it or take a screenshot if you would like assistance. Otherwise, I agree with @ScottCraner

Comment: Link worked for me and that was before any comments were posted.  I would have preferred a screen shot though and not going to an external site.

Comment: The Link works for me , I posted a screenshot of what the worksheet looks like now,    rows 8, 10, 12,  13,   and down , need to have a yellow name because they have close to and expired dates.        http://imgur.com/PsDLHIX

Answer (score 0):

Set your conditional formatting for the person's name cell and use formula as the method.  for the formula use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($D3:$S3<NOW()+DATE(0,6,0))*($D3:$S3<>""))>0
```

You may need to change the reference range.  IF you select all the names and the top name is the active cell, you can use this formula as long as the row numbers are not locked and they have been updated to be the same row as the active cell in the selection.